# Google play services error in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play-services

I installed google play services package . After the installation I am getting errors in my whole eclipse projects. I am not able to figure out why this is happening.

Comment: Did you try restarting eclipse ?

Comment: yes, I restarted eclipse after the installation.

Comment: Have you added the google play services library to you workspace and linked it to your android project?

Comment: did you try `Project > Clean` from the main menu bar?

Comment: yes. I also tried that.

Comment: @user3467204 you need to post the errors. How did you reference the library project??

Comment: All my projects are showing up red cross mark . I can't run them .

Comment: Does you android project's properties -> android tab look somewhat like this: http://gyazo.com/854fd2a9e859c30e9eba8afd1a4b5480?

Comment: @ Remyoman : I know it should look like the one that you refer but right now,  on my screen all that I can see is just the red cross marks over all the projects .

Comment: @ Remyoman.. I have configured it like your reference. Now I am getting this error:- google-play-services_lib] Unable to resolve target 'android-9'

Answer (score 1):

Add Google play service lib into your workspace 
link this lib to your project using built path 
clear your project 
check google play service version is added in to your manifest file

Comment: Hi , Previous error is resolved, Now I am getting this error:- google-play-services_lib] Unable to resolve target 'android-9'

Comment: Right click on your google-play-services-lib project and go to properties. Click on Android from left side and select appropriate build target from the list